# In bluetooth protocol , what is the difference between LT_ADDR and LLID of L2CAP layer

Tags: bluetooth

I feel like both are used to identify logical channel that a physical channel is divided into. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

Both terms are relevant to Bluetooth Logical Links definitions.

**LT Address** is defined in Link Control; it is being used In the packet header. 
In general, It allows a Bluetooth (BR/EDR) slave to determine that a certain packet was addressed to it.

**LLID** is defined in the packet payload header and is used to **distinguish between**:

- **ACL-C** (Link Management Protocol) **message**
- **ACL-U** (L2CAP - Logical Link Control and Adaptation Protocol) **message**

---

**Detailed answer** (all page references address the BT Spec 5.0):

**LT Address** is defined in the Bluetooth Baseband Specification and stands for Logical Transport Address.
It is defined in **Link Control** layer for the master to be able to address its various slaves within the piconet. 
Each slave is assigned with a unique 3-bit LT_ADDR (page 390):

> The primary LT_ADDR shall be assigned by the master to the slave when
>   the slave is activated. This is either at connection establishment or
>   role switch, when the primary LT_ADDR is carried in the FHS payload.

LLID term is defined in ACL-C and ACL-U (=> L2CAP) logical links:
It is included in the packet payload header to determine if a packet is ACL-C (LMP) or ACL-U (L2CAP):

ACL-C (page 398):

> The ACL-C and ASB-C logical links are indicated by the LLID code 11b
>   in the payload header.

ACL-U (page 399):

> For fragmented messages, the start packet shall use anLLID code of
>   10b in the payload header.  Remaining continuation packets shall use
>   LLID code 01b.  If there is no fragmentation, all packets shall use
>   the LLID start code 10b.

There’s another usage of the LLID term in context of Bluetooth Low Energy (LE) which is not covered here.

Answer (score 0):

The `Logical Link Control and Adaptation Layer Protocol` (**L2CAP**) is layered over the Baseband Protocol and resides in the data link layer. It provides connection-oriented and connectionless data services to upper layer protocols with protocol multiplexing capability, segmentation and reassembly operation, and group abstractions. L2CAP permits higher level protocols and applications to transmit and receive L2CAP data packets up to 64 kilobytes in length.

[image: L2CAP architecture block]

```
                              Fig1: L2CAP architecture block
```

**Link Controller (LC)**

The standard data packet used at the LC level comprises an `Access Code`, `Packet Header`, `Payload Header`, `Payload` and [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). This standard packet will be used to encompass data to and from the upper-layers of the protocol stack.
[image]

```
                              Fig1: Packet structure at LC
```

- **Packet Header**

  Header comprises of six fields `LT_ADDR`,`TYPE`,`FLOW`,`ARQN`,`SEQN` and `HEC`

  [image]

  - **LT_ADDR** (Logical Transport Address) : LT_ADDR comprises of a 3-bit field, which denotes an active slave within a [piconet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piconet) (**Note**: that the master is not assigned a LT_ADDR).
- **Payload**

  - **LLID** (Logical Link Identifier) : Within such logical transports, the logical link is identified by the **LLID** bits in the payload header of baseband packets that carry a data payload.

**Ref :**

[BLE5-Stack User's Guide](http://dev.ti.com/tirex/content/simplelink_cc2640r2_sdk_1_35_00_33/docs/ble5stack/ble_user_guide/html/ble-stack/l2cap.html)
[Developing Practical Wireless Applications](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9781555583101/developing-practical-wireless-applications)
[Bluetooth Specification](https://www.labri.fr/perso/betrema/SR/BT12.pdf) - `Vol 0`